# Oozie credentials kerberos

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, oozie

Oozie credentials for Kerberos cluster are working well with hive and hbase
Suppose consider an example where I have an oozie shell action that reads hdfs files. Oozie credentials are not coming to help in such a case.
In an oozie workflow that has a combination of different actions it gets very weird to use credentials in some places and kinit(using keytab and principal) in other places.
Please suggest, If there is an alternative to access hdfs with oozie credentials??

Comment: AFAIK Oozie **implicitly** manages credentials for YARN and HDFS -- I never had any issue running CLI commands such as `hdfs dfs -ls` in a Shell action. Did you try?

Comment: It is a problem with my configuration. I am able to resolve it with and access hdfs without any issue

Comment: Hi  Samson Scharfrichter, I would like to know which one is the recommended approach to make oozie workflow to work with kerberos. Is it better to go ahead with credentials or via uploading keytab in hdfs and doing kinit

Comment: Credentials are a built-in feature, relying on the fact that `oozie` service account is privileged and can impersonate any user (a "proxy account" in Hadoop jargon). They are supposed to work transparently with any action that supports them natively -- e.g. `hcat` creds with Hive _(fat client)_ and Pig and Spark actions, `hive2` with Hive2 _(thin client)_ etc.

Comment: For Java action it's a bit different, you have to grab the tokens from a file shipped by Oozie server inside the YARN container. For Shell action - well, except for Hadoop utilities that can grab the tokens automatically, you may have to use `kinit` on a keytab file as a workaround. But make sure that you set appropriate access privs on the keytab file on HDFS!! And make sure you don't trash the default Kerberos credential cache on Linux by setting `KRB5CCNAME` to a local, temporary file!!!!!!!!!!!